# Javascript Date from 20/11/2010 to November 20th, 2010?

Tags: javascript

I have a string value something like the below values

```
9/21/2010
9/24/2010
```

And I want to convert those to

```
September 21nd, 2010
September 24th, 2010
```

is there an easy way of doing this? Or do I have to do it the hard way?

**PS. This is strictly javascript, please don't post jQuery examples.**

Thanks!

Comment: What is "the hard way"? The standard way of doing this is with string formatting.

Comment: Side note: The example in your title is `DD/MM/YYYY` but in your question the example is `MM/DD/YYYY`...

Comment: Hard way = split it into an array, create array of months and days with ending and compare then format the string.

Comment: there's datejs (datejs.com) if you want to do some hardcore dating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "the hard way". One way is to split the date into it's components and convert to date (assuming US m/d/y format) and then format the date object how you want:

```
function toDate(s) {
  var bits = s.split('/');
  return new Date(bits[2], bits[0] - 1, bits[1]);
}


function addOrdinal(n) {
  var ords = ['th','st','nd','rd'];
  var o = ('' + (n%10))
  if (n > 10 && n < 14) {
    return n + 'th';
  } else {
    return n + (ords[o] || 'th');
  }
}


function formatDate(d) {
  var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June',
                'July','August','September','October','November','December'];
  return months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + addOrdinal(d.getDate()) + ', ' + d.getFullYear();
}
```

Another is to just convert the month to its name:

```
function reFormatDate(s) {
  var bits = s.split('/');
  var months = [,'January','February','March','April','May','June',
                'July','August','September','October','November','December'];
  return months[bits[0]] + ' ' + addOrdinal(bits[1]) + ', ' + bits[2];
}
```

#### Edit

Added the ordinal to date.

Comment: That doesn't clearly output it using the `st`, `nd`, `rd`, etc. on the end of the day.

Comment: But it does enough to get a correct answer from me. Adding on `var suff = ['st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','nd','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th'];`

Answer (score 1):

You can create new date by just supplying a string to the `Date()` constructor.

```
var date = new Date("9/21/2010");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

However, to display the date as a string in a customizable way, you'll need to either do it the hard way or using a library, such as dateJS. Javascript provides a couple of output formats for dates, but none of them is especially customizable.

Answer (score 0):

```
function niceDate(dateString) {
    var m = [,'January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
              'August','September','October','November','December'];
    var s = ['th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th'];
    var d = dateString.split('/');
    return(m[d[0]-1] + ' ' + d[1] + s[d[1]>4&&d[1]<20?4:d[1]%10] + ', ' + d[2]);
}
```